# jQuery - Grid returns with uneven rows and columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The input field decreases/increases the grid size, however, the grid row and column are never even.

**JS fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/4mph9ewk/

**Here is what I tried:**
1. I looked into my CSS file and looked at line 31 - 44. I used flexbox to make grid so I thought float left would work more effectively.

2. In my js file, there is nested for loop in my main() function so before that, I used one for loop and just squared the boxSide (boxSide is set equal to a parameter which is controlled from the input field).

CSS

```
 .container {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }

    .title header h1 {
        margin: 1em 0em 1em 0;
    }

    .containerGrid {
        display: flex;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        margin-bottom: 5em;

    }

    .cell {
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        border-radius: 3px;
        border: 0.5px solid var(--black-color);
    }
```

JavaScript

```
            function reset(length) {
        boxSide = length;
        main();
        $(".cell").css({
                        "opacity": "0.1",
                        "border": "0.5px solid black",
                        "backgroundColor": "transparent"});
    }

    /*-- ------------------------- 
            Creates the Grid 
    ------------------------------*/
    function main() {
        $($containerGrid).empty();
        for (let row = 1; row < boxSide; row++) {
            for (let column = 0; column < boxSide; column++) {
                $(".cell").css("height", `${100 / boxSide}%`);
                $(".cell").css("width", `${100 / boxSide}%`);
                createCell()
            }
        }
    }

    function createCell() {
        const $cell = $('<div class="cell"></div>');
        $cell.css("opacity", "0.1");
        $containerGrid.append($cell);
    }

    main();
```

If you enter 3 into the input field you would expect a 3 x 3 well it turns out to be a 3 x 2 with a little square on the bottom row, last column so that is completely wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay, 3 changes:

1. You are running the row loop from 1 to box size, do it from 0 - boxsize, else you will get one less row
2. Change the formula of the cell from % to px, and divide your container grid by box size and remove 1 px for the margins

```js
$(".cell").css("height", `${(300 / boxSide)-1}px`);
$(".cell").css("width", `${(300 / boxSide)-1}px`);
```

3. Finally, move your cell CSS out of the loop and run it once in main() function for all the cells at once.

**Working Demo**

<kbd>[JS FIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/fzkjyq4L/)</kbd>

Comment: This helped a lot! thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: By the way, was this question good? I got ghosted once and yelled at for asking bad questions so just wondering if this question was good. Once again thank you!

Comment: yes, this time it was good but very lengthy though ;) if it helped, please do upvote and accept the answer. You can also see the working fiddle in the answer

Comment: It says I don't have enough reputation but it is recorded and next time I ask a question I'll keep it short! And I accepted your answer, thank you.